# How to suppress KeyboardInterrupt output when running a python script on bash?

Tags: python, bash

I decide to run a python script from my bash terminal prompt, e.g. running `$ python my_script.py`.

I then decide to press `Ctrl-C` to kill this active process.

Then, the process dies, and some output error comes to the terminal, that may look like:

```
^C
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
KeyboardInterrupt
```

How can I suppress this output from the bash/terminal side while **still** using `Ctrl-C`.

From [this comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48425/how-to-stop-the-loop-bash-script-in-terminal/48465#comment67514_48432) I learned that you can use `Ctrl-\` to quit the process, which is apparently different than `Ctrl-C`. It seems to suppress any output.

However, if I simply run `$ python` and run some code within the interactive python shell, using `Ctrl-\` will completely quit the Python shell process, while `Ctrl-C` just kills that code that I had just execute (like a for loop) but preserves the Python shell process.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a try-except block:
Here in the below code, I am just printing some numbers as an example, replace that with your code:

---

```
import sys
try:
    # your code
    for i in range(1000000):
        print(i)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: Thank you - This is a good solution to be applied within the python code. I'll keep it in mind. However, I'm wondering about what you can do if something like this isn't in the python code - could you do something with bash/terminal signals?

Comment: @I_Don't_Code see my answer if you are looking for that kind of solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can do `python script.py 2>/dev/null` since you're using bash.

The **2** means it sends **stderr** to a special file **/dev/null** which is always empty, to which this script will now send its output to.

If you had no **2**, it would suppress standard output (i.e. **stdout**) but not errors.

If you wanted to suppress both, you could do `> /dev/null 2>&1`, since 1 is stdout, and stdout is now being routed to devnull.

Essentially, you are sending the error traceback, instead of to the standard stderr location (your screen), to a blank file.

Comment: Works like a charm! It does have strange behavior when I run an interactive python shell such as running ```python 2>/dev/null```. If I run a very long for loop in that interactive python session, and press ```Ctrl-C```, it doesn't show the error messages. So aside from the other strange behavior, it's a success!